# Paste float numbers on an Excel file

Tags: excel

I have a `.txt` file with lot of lines and each one looks like this

```
1479581952000 $ Alex $ 417 $ 658.4545 $ 5678 $ JHV
```

When I copy and paste the text the float numbers, `658.4545` in this example become `6584545`. Excel just drop the point. How can I solve this? I am using `Excel 14.3.0` on `mac`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be because of some cache issue.

First, open an empty sheet and enter some character in the cell A1.
Click on the column A1 and then using the 'Text to columns' option in your data tab. Try to convert the column using a delimited option with only $ as a delimiter and uncheck all other delimiters and Click OK for all other options. With this, you are clearing all other previous cache.

Once it is done, select all cells in that sheet, and delete the content.
Now try to copy and paste your text and see.